# Using Selenium webdriver when tried to get the CSS property of background-color, it returned ‘transparent’

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium Webdriver in Java, when I try to get the background color I get the result as Transparent instead of the hex value.

```
if(elementName.contains("Background"))
  getColor = driver.findElement(By.xpath(eleXPath)).getCssValue("background-color");

String[] numbers = getColor.replace("rgba(", "").replace(")", "").split(",");
int r = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0].trim());
int g = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1].trim());
int b = Integer.parseInt(numbers[2].trim());
hex = "#" + Integer.toHexString(r) + Integer.toHexString(g) + Integer.toHexString(b);
String[] numbers = getColor.replace("rgba(", "").replace(")", "").split(",");
```

The above code returns as "transparent"

Comment: Check your xpath points to correct location. And If the Background-color is transparent - it will bring transparent.

Answer (score -1):

try the following code :

```
((JavascriptExecuter)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].style.background-color", element);
```

Comment: Why would be a useful addition to this answer. What is this doing that the other code is not?

Comment: Please explain your answer a little to make it useful for all readers.

Comment: Your answer will bring the background-color, as same as what hari_1009 tried. Without knowing the correct location, how we can get the correct value?